# getting getNetworkPrefixLength() -1 (incorrect) in Windows 8 and 20 (correct) in windows XP

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to get subnet mask for my network interface in java.
My IP Address is 172.16.179.197
Subnet Mask: 255.255.240.0

my code

ifa.getAddress().getHostAddress() gives Ip address
but 
ifa.getNetworkPrefixLength() gives -1 in Windows 7/8 but gives 20 in windows xp

how to get netprifix or subnet mask for subnet 255.255.240.0 by java

Comment: Please answer now. I had updated my Question